# How to find average after joining two datasets and grouping, in Pig

Tags: apache-pig

I have two data sets, EmployeeDetail that contains 4 columns(id, name, gender, location) and SalaryDetail(id, salary). I joined both dats sets and grouped them as location.

```
EmpDetail = load '/Users/bmohanty6/EmployeeDetails/EmpDetail.txt' as (id:int, name:chararray, gender:chararray, location:chararray);
SalaryDetail = load '/Users/bmohanty6/EmployeeDetails/EmpSalary.txt' as (id:int, salary:float);                                     
JoinedEmpDetail = join EmpDetail by id, SalaryDetail by id;                                                                         
GroupedByLocation = group JoinedEmpDetail by location;
```

DUMP GroupedByLocation gives me the correct result I expect. Now when I try to take average using below line,

```
AverageSalary = foreach GroupedByLocation generate group, AVG(SalaryDetail.salary);
```

It throws below error.

```
<line 11, column 58> Could not infer the matching function for org.apache.pig.builtin.AVG as multiple or none of them fit. Please use an explicit cast.
```

I also tried in following way. But got same error.

```
AverageSalary = foreach GroupedByLocation {
  Sum = SUM(SalaryDetail.salary);
  Count = COUNT(SalaryDetail.salary);
  avgSal = Sum/Count;
  generate group as location, avgSal;
  };
```

This time error was:

```
Could not infer the matching function for org.apache.pig.builtin.SUM as multiple or none of them fit. Please use an explicit cast.
```

Can anyone please suggest me a correct way of doing it.

Thanks **Sivasakthi Jayaraman** for answering my question.

```
AverageSalary = foreach GroupedByLocation generate group, AVG(JoinedEmpDetail.SalaryDetail::salary);
```

This gives me the average salary per each location.
Now I tried to find out average salary per gender in each `location`. So I tried to group by `gender` inside `GroupedByLocation` variable. But facing some issues in it.

```
GroupdByGender = foreach GroupedByLocation { 
genderGrp = group JoinedEmpDetail by JoinedEmpDetail.EmpDetail::gender;
avgSalary = foreach genderGrp generate group, AVG(JoinedEmpDetail.SalaryDetail::salary);
generate group as location, JoinedEmpDetail.EmpDetail::gender, avgSalary;
};
```

I got this error

```
Syntax error, unexpected symbol at or near 'JoinedEmpDetail'
```

Can anyone please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access `salary` column like this, first you need to project the `JoinedEmpDetail` relation and then access the `salary` column.

Can you try the below stmt?

```
AverageSalary = foreach GroupedByLocation generate group, AVG(JoinedEmpDetail.SalaryDetail::salary);
```

Comment: I tried to find out average salary per gender in each location. So I tried to group by gender inside GroupedByLocation variable. But facing some issues in it. I have updated the question as well.

Comment: @Biswa, once the answer is accepted, please don't update the same question, ppl will not look into this. Could you please post this as a new question and also provide some sample input data and the expected output.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I posted a new question here.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27791699/find-average-by-joining-two-datasets

Comment: @Biswa,posted the answer,please check it.