# Find average by joining two datasets

Tags: apache-pig, inner-join

I have two data sets ,

```
EmployeeDetail(data set 1):- 
   id  
   name
   gender
   location 

SalaryDetail(data set 2):-
   id
   salary
```

I need to join both and find out average salary of male and female in each location. So I tried following code .

```
EmpDetail = load '/Users/bmohanty6/EmployeeDetails/EmpDetail.txt' as 
(id:int, name:chararray, gender:chararray, location:chararray);
SalaryDetail = load '/Users/bmohanty6/EmployeeDetails/EmpSalary.txt' as 
(id:int, salary:float);                                     
JoinedEmpDetail = join EmpDetail by id, SalaryDetail by
id;                                                                         
GroupedByLocation = group JoinedEmpDetail by location;
AverageSalary = foreach GroupedByLocation { 
genderGrp = group JoinedEmpDetail by JoinedEmpDetail.EmpDetail::gender;
avgSalary = foreach genderGrp generate group, 
AVG(JoinedEmpDetail.SalaryDetail::salary);
generate group as location, JoinedEmpDetail.EmpDetail::gender, avgSalary;
};
```

But it is throwing below error

```
<line 6, column 22>  Syntax error, unexpected symbol at or near 
'JoinedEmpDetail'
```

Can anyone please help where am I doing the mistake or how to do it properly?

For more clarity about my requirement I am giving some sample data sets.

***EmpDetail.txt***

```
1   Biswa   Male    Bangalore
12  Bratati Mahapatra   Female  Chennai
2   Bibhu kalyan    Male    Bangalore
3   Chinta  Male    Mumbai
10  Amrit Anand Male    Bangalore
11  Sateesh panda   Male    Bangalore
4   Kirti Kumar Male    Mumbai
6   Shruthi Female  Chennai
7   Vijay   Male    Chennai
5   Bibhu   Male    Chennai
9   Bratati  Mohanty    Female  Bangalore
8   Rupa Mahapatra  Female  Bangalore
13  Salini  Female  Mumbai
14  Priyanka Chopra Female  Mumbai
```

***EmpSalary.txt***

```
1   10000
12  12000
2   15900
3   9000
10  8000
11  13400
4   7600
6   22000
7   17000
5   16800
9   9800
8   10000
13  11000
14  12500
```

Final result I need is:

```
Mumbai male <avgsalary amount>
Mumbai female <avgsalary amount>
Bangalore male <avgsalary amount>
Bangalore female <avgsalary amount>
Chennai male <avgsalary amount>
Chennai female <avgsalary amount>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this problem using simple `foreach stmt` so don't go for nested foreach stmt.

`Group command` will not work inside nested Foreach, its restricted in pig. Only few commands are allowed inside the nested foreach (CROSS, DISTINCT, FILTER, FOREACH, LIMIT, and ORDER BY).

Can you change your script like this?

```
EmpDetail = load '/Users/bmohanty6/EmployeeDetails/EmpDetail.txt' as (id:int, name:chararray, gender:chararray, location:chararray);
SalaryDetail = load '/Users/bmohanty6/EmployeeDetails/EmpSalary.txt' as (id:int, salary:float);                                     
JoinedEmpDetail = join EmpDetail by id, SalaryDetail by id;
GroupedByLocation = group JoinedEmpDetail by (location,gender);
AverageSalary = FOREACH GroupedByLocation GENERATE FLATTEN(group),AVG(JoinedEmpDetail.SalaryDetail::salary);
DUMP AverageSalary;
```

**Output:**

```
(Mumbai,Male,8300.0)
(Mumbai,Female,11750.0)
(Chennai,Male,16900.0)
(Chennai,Female,17000.0)
(Bangalore,Male,11825.0)
(Bangalore,Female,9900.0)
```

Comment: It worked fine. Thanks a lot for clarifying my mistake.